# coverpoint weight is not catching in simulator

Tags: system-verilog, cadence

I've written a coverage collection code that contains coverpoints and crosses , I don't want some of the coverpoints to affect the collection percentage , so I used option.weight=0 in them , but when I open the simulator , it tells me that the weight is 1 (default value) ! .
why doesn't my change catch ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at per type coverage (as opposed to per instance coverage). In that case, you should set `type_option.weight`.